# Hide Javascript comments in chrome dev tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm using chrome dev tools to debug and understand code from a javascript-based repo.

I write down lots of inline comments on my forked repo. So I can jot down the insights I get during each debug iteration. My forked repo is polluted with comments as a result. It makes it a bit hard to read the source material in the debugger.

What would be nice is if I could just "hide" javascript comments in chrome dev tools.

Does such a thing exist? It seems like a feature the browser should be able to handle. All I could find is the ability to hide html comments only.

[image]

Comment: A word of advice, if you start with TDD your test cases end up becoming great documentation for your code. Leaving comments everywhere isn't the best way to go as you mentioned they end up all over the place.

Comment: I'll look into test driven development thanks for the input

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to do what you're asking. The closest you could get is to have an automated task run over your JavaScript to actually remove the comments, but this would actually remove them, not just hide them visually.

Comment: hm okay I guess I might find some gulp or webpack tools for automating this later if it becomes a bigger problem for me

Comment: That would be the approach I would use - you can use the same approach to get rid of `console.log` stuff which is useful also.